# Magento - adding an item to cart creates an endless loop (I think)

Tags: php, magento

I don't know what i did or what I changed, but I had a cart that was working fine on Wednesday. Today I made some minor changes (implemented a newsletter, laid out the search) and now when I add something to the cart, it gets stuck in what appears to be an endless loop.

This is what I see after about 3-4 seconds of running the add to cart page in Firefox when I turn on the Debug Profiler (sorry it's such a mess...I can't copy it from View Source without FF crashing, which means this is the best I can do):

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Address_Item_Collection Object ( [_model:protected] => sales/quote_address_item [_resourceModel:protected] => sales/quote_address_item [_resource:protected] => Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Address_Item Object ( [_resources:protected] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource Object ( [_connectionTypes:protected] => Array ( ) [_connections:protected] => Array ( [core_read] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql Object ( [_defaultStmtClass:protected] => Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql [_transactionLevel:protected] => 2 [_connectionFlagsSet:protected] => 1 [_ddlCache:protected] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [magento_eav_attribute] => Array ( [attribute_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => attribute_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 1 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => 1 [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 1 [IDENTITY] => 1 ) [entity_type_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => entity_type_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 2 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [attribute_code] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => attribute_code [COLUMN_POSITION] => 3 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [attribute_model] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => attribute_model [COLUMN_POSITION] => 4 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [backend_model] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => backend_model [COLUMN_POSITION] => 5 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [backend_type] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => backend_type [COLUMN_POSITION] => 6 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => static [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => 8 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [backend_table] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => backend_table [COLUMN_POSITION] => 7 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [frontend_model] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => frontend_model [COLUMN_POSITION] => 8 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [frontend_input] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => frontend_input [COLUMN_POSITION] => 9 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 50 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [frontend_label] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => frontend_label [COLUMN_POSITION] => 10 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [frontend_class] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => frontend_class [COLUMN_POSITION] => 11 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [source_model] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => source_model [COLUMN_POSITION] => 12 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [is_required] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => is_required [COLUMN_POSITION] => 13 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [is_user_defined] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => is_user_defined [COLUMN_POSITION] => 14 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [default_value] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => default_value [COLUMN_POSITION] => 15 [DATA_TYPE] => text [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [is_unique] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => is_unique [COLUMN_POSITION] => 16 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [note] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => note [COLUMN_POSITION] => 17 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) ) [magento_customer_eav_attribute] => Array ( [attribute_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => attribute_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 1 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => 1 [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 1 [IDENTITY] => ) [is_visible] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => is_visible [COLUMN_POSITION] => 2 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 1 [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [input_filter] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => input_filter [COLUMN_POSITION] => 3 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [multiline_count] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => multiline_count [COLUMN_POSITION] => 4 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 1 [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [validate_rules] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => validate_rules [COLUMN_POSITION] => 5 [DATA_TYPE] => text [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [is_system] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => is_system [COLUMN_POSITION] => 6 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [sort_order] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => sort_order [COLUMN_POSITION] => 7 [DATA_TYPE] => int [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [data_model] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute [COLUMN_NAME] => data_model [COLUMN_POSITION] => 8 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) ) [magento_customer_eav_attribute_website] => Array ( [attribute_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute_website [COLUMN_NAME] => attribute_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 1 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => 1 [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 1 [IDENTITY] => ) [website_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute_website [COLUMN_NAME] => website_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 2 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => 1 [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 2 [IDENTITY] => ) [is_visible] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute_website [COLUMN_NAME] => is_visible [COLUMN_POSITION] => 3 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [is_required] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute_website [COLUMN_NAME] => is_required [COLUMN_POSITION] => 4 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [default_value] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute_website [COLUMN_NAME] => default_value [COLUMN_POSITION] => 5 [DATA_TYPE] => text [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [multiline_count] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_customer_eav_attribute_website [COLUMN_NAME] => multiline_count [COLUMN_POSITION] => 6 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) ) [magento_sales_flat_quote] => Array ( [entity_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => entity_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 1 [DATA_TYPE] => int [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => 1 [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 1 [IDENTITY] => 1 ) [store_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => store_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 2 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [created_at] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => created_at [COLUMN_POSITION] => 3 [DATA_TYPE] => timestamp [DEFAULT] => CURRENT_TIMESTAMP [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [updated_at] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => updated_at [COLUMN_POSITION] => 4 [DATA_TYPE] => timestamp [DEFAULT] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [converted_at] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => converted_at [COLUMN_POSITION] => 5 [DATA_TYPE] => timestamp [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [is_active] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => is_active [COLUMN_POSITION] => 6 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 1 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [is_virtual] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => is_virtual [COLUMN_POSITION] => 7 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [is_multi_shipping] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => is_multi_shipping [COLUMN_POSITION] => 8 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [items_count] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => items_count [COLUMN_POSITION] => 9 [DATA_TYPE] => int [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [items_qty] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => items_qty [COLUMN_POSITION] => 10 [DATA_TYPE] => decimal [DEFAULT] => 0.0000 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => 4 [PRECISION] => 12 [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [orig_order_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => orig_order_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 11 [DATA_TYPE] => int [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [store_to_base_rate] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => store_to_base_rate [COLUMN_POSITION] => 12 [DATA_TYPE] => decimal [DEFAULT] => 0.0000 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => 4 [PRECISION] => 12 [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [store_to_quote_rate] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => store_to_quote_rate [COLUMN_POSITION] => 13 [DATA_TYPE] => decimal [DEFAULT] => 0.0000 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => 4 [PRECISION] => 12 [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [base_currency_code] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => base_currency_code [COLUMN_POSITION] => 14 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [store_currency_code] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => store_currency_code [COLUMN_POSITION] => 15 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [quote_currency_code] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => quote_currency_code [COLUMN_POSITION] => 16 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [grand_total] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => grand_total [COLUMN_POSITION] => 17 [DATA_TYPE] => decimal [DEFAULT] => 0.0000 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => 4 [PRECISION] => 12 [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [base_grand_total] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => base_grand_total [COLUMN_POSITION] => 18 [DATA_TYPE] => decimal [DEFAULT] => 0.0000 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => 4 [PRECISION] => 12 [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [checkout_method] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => checkout_method [COLUMN_POSITION] => 19 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 20 [DATA_TYPE] => int [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_tax_class_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_tax_class_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 21 [DATA_TYPE] => int [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_group_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_group_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 22 [DATA_TYPE] => int [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_email] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_email [COLUMN_POSITION] => 23 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_prefix] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_prefix [COLUMN_POSITION] => 24 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 40 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_firstname] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_firstname [COLUMN_POSITION] => 25 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_middlename] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_middlename [COLUMN_POSITION] => 26 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 40 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_lastname] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_lastname [COLUMN_POSITION] => 27 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_suffix] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_suffix [COLUMN_POSITION] => 28 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 40 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_dob] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_dob [COLUMN_POSITION] => 29 [DATA_TYPE] => datetime [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_note] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_note [COLUMN_POSITION] => 30 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_note_notify] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_note_notify [COLUMN_POSITION] => 31 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 1 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_is_guest] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_is_guest [COLUMN_POSITION] => 32 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [remote_ip] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => remote_ip [COLUMN_POSITION] => 33 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 32 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [applied_rule_ids] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => applied_rule_ids [COLUMN_POSITION] => 34 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [reserved_order_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => reserved_order_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 35 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 64 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [password_hash] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => password_hash [COLUMN_POSITION] => 36 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [coupon_code] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => coupon_code [COLUMN_POSITION] => 37 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [global_currency_code] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => global_currency_code [COLUMN_POSITION] => 38 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [base_to_global_rate] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => base_to_global_rate [COLUMN_POSITION] => 39 [DATA_TYPE] => decimal [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => 4 [PRECISION] => 12 [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [base_to_quote_rate] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => base_to_quote_rate [COLUMN_POSITION] => 40 [DATA_TYPE] => decimal [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => 4 [PRECISION] => 12 [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_taxvat] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_taxvat [COLUMN_POSITION] => 41 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [customer_gender] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => customer_gender [COLUMN_POSITION] => 42 [DATA_TYPE] => varchar [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => 255 [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [subtotal] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => subtotal [COLUMN_POSITION] => 43 [DATA_TYPE] => decimal [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => 4 [PRECISION] => 12 [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [base_subtotal] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => base_subtotal [COLUMN_POSITION] => 44 [DATA_TYPE] => decimal [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => 4 [PRECISION] => 12 [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [subtotal_with_discount] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => subtotal_with_discount [COLUMN_POSITION] => 45 [DATA_TYPE] => decimal [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => 4 [PRECISION] => 12 [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [base_subtotal_with_discount] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => base_subtotal_with_discount [COLUMN_POSITION] => 46 [DATA_TYPE] => decimal [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => 4 [PRECISION] => 12 [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [is_changed] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => is_changed [COLUMN_POSITION] => 47 [DATA_TYPE] => int [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [trigger_recollect] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => trigger_recollect [COLUMN_POSITION] => 48 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [ext_shipping_info] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => ext_shipping_info [COLUMN_POSITION] => 49 [DATA_TYPE] => text [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [gift_message_id] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => gift_message_id [COLUMN_POSITION] => 50 [DATA_TYPE] => int [DEFAULT] => [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) [is_persistent] => Array ( [SCHEMA_NAME] => [TABLE_NAME] => magento_sales_flat_quote [COLUMN_NAME] => is_persistent [COLUMN_POSITION] => 51 [DATA_TYPE] => smallint [DEFAULT] => 0 [NULLABLE] => 1 [LENGTH] => [SCALE] => [PRECISION] => [UNSIGNED] => 1 [PRIMARY] => [PRIMARY_POSITION] => [IDENTITY] => ) )
```

The first question I have is what is causing this and where I would look to debug it. I'm not a PHP guy by nature, but I can hack it. I'm just not sure what/where to hack.

I've disabled EAV, CONFIG_API and COLLECTION_DATA caching based on what I read in the Magento forums. I've cleared the cache several times. I've rebuilt indices. I altered .htaccess to speed things up (which led to Chrome crashing faster, but that was about it).

The second question I have is why there's a quote object even being called in the first place. This is a simple product/shopping cart. No customizations or colors. Just a product. That's it, that's all. What's the point of the quote thing?

Thanks.  By the way, this is Magento 1.6.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Disable all magento caches ("System" => "Cache Management")
Also press the "Flush magento cache" button on this page.

"System" => "Index management" and re-index all the data.

Also, delete the entire contents of ./var/cache (it will remake the files and directories it needs next time it runs).

If this doesn't fix it. Go to: "system" => "configuration" => "advanced" (under the advanced tab).
In turn, disable each of your new extensions until the system starts working. That will tell you what extension is broken.

From what you output, it looks like something is running either the print_r or var_dump php functions. These are a bad idea most of the time in Magento as the objects can get very large and so take a long time to dump to the screen.

Once you find out what extension is failing. Search the code for both of these functions and remove each reference you find.